# Generic search with expression trees gives System.NullReferenceException for nullable fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a generic crud controller and I try to implement a generic search method.

The code works well with non-nullable fields, but the problem is when I search nullable fields. I get

> System.NullReferenceException

```
protected IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> filterable, string ParameterValue)
{
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(ParameterValue);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
    MemberExpression[] members = new MemberExpression[filterProps.Count()];
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < filterProps.Count(); i++)
    {
        members[i] = Expression.Property(parameter, filterProps[i]);
    }

    Expression predicate = null;
    foreach (var item in members)
    {
        MethodCallExpression callExpression = Expression.Call(item, method, constant);
        predicate = predicate == null ? (Expression)callExpression : Expression.OrElse(predicate, callExpression);
    }

    var Lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

    return filterable.Where(Lambda);
}
```

when I query a non-null column as *"username"* the code works fine, but I get `System.NullReferenceException` when I try to query a nullable column as *"name"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null check on the member will need to be included to make sure the member call can be invoked without exception.

```
//...omitted for brevity


Expression predicate = null;
foreach (var member in members) {
    //e => e.Member != null
    BinaryExpression nullExpression = Expression.NotEqual(member, Expression.Constant(null));
    //e => e.Member.StartsWith(value)
    MethodCallExpression callExpression = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);
    //e => e.Member != null && e.Member.StartsWith(value)
    BinaryExpression filterExpression = Expression.AndAlso(nullExpression, callExpression);

    predicate = predicate == null ? (Expression)filterExpression : Expression.OrElse(predicate, filterExpression);
}


//...omitted for brevity
```

Comments added so you see the expression as it is being built.

Comment: So a null check is necessary. Thank you so much, your help came just when I was about to give up.

Comment: @GuillermoVerón well given that there are possible null columns/properties, it would be safer to check for null instead of trying to invoke a member on a null object. Which is what was causing the null reference errors.